# Sync PostgreSQL with Cloud and multi Local Locations

Tags: postgresql, replication, clustering, failover, data-synchronization

I need help with a complex (for me) multi server setup with PostgreSQL.

I have to setup a Cloud Server and 3 Local Servers for our company.

**Each Server will have:**

Linux Ubuntu 16.04

Docker

PostgreSQL 9.6

Nginx

(maybe also Rancher 1.6 for container Management)

Users will normally connect to the Cloud instance for work.
But if the Cloud is down, users need to access local on each location.

How can i realize this scenario? 
What should i use for PostgreSQL replication or sync?

Thanks in advance

Kevin

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you want multi-master replication, which is much harder than unidirectional replication.  That is not natively supported by the community version of PostgreSQL, but there are tools you can use, and proprietary forks.  See the discussion at https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Multimaster for a starter.